# How can I restart the spring batch remote partitioning job after it is failed

Tags: spring-batch

We are writing a batch job using spring batch and we are following remote partitioning approach. We are running the master on standalone app and slaves on app server. we are facing a issue, master is failing after certain partitions are completed. I was just wondering how can i trigger the job for remaining work?

Thanks in advance!!

--Maddy

Comment: Are the slaves failing?  They may be completing their work...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..slaves are not failing, I am generating a report after completion of master step..because of the master step is failing, i am not able proceed further..How can i handle this kind of situation?

Comment: One more question is if some slaves fail, how can we restart the job only for failed slaves?

Comment: If you restart the master, it should restart the slaves.  That being said, you need to be aware of how you design your job to prevent duplicate processing of items.  In the end, the master and each slave is an independent step and so restarting the job will restart those steps just like any other step.

Comment: Thanks for your response..I am little confused, I am trying to skip the completed steps and re-run failed/remaining steps..Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: Spring Batch won't rerun the steps that are completed by default unless you configure them to be rerun.  Aka, what you're asking for is the default behavior.